# Can I read the value of a variable in an asp file from a second asp file?

Tags: asp-classic

I have an asp file that stores some values that are then used on an included template file. Like this:

```
dim mediaSrc()

ReDim mediaSrc(2)
mediaSrc(0) = "http://server.com/path/to/file.mp3"
mediaSrc(1) = "http://server.com/path/to/file.mp3"
mediaSrc(2) = "http://server.com/path/to/file.mp3"

<!--#include virtual="/path/to/include.asp" -->
```

I have a second asp file in which I want to include information from several of these first files. So I might have something like:

```
dim fileSrc()

ReDim fileSrc(2)
fileSrc(0) = "http://server.com/path/to/firstfile.asp"
fileSrc(1) = "http://server.com/path/to/secondfile.asp"
fileSrc(2) = "http://server.com/path/to/finalfile.asp"
```

Can I, in that second asp file, get a reference to the variables set in the first asp files?

I'd like to do something like:

```
fileSrc(0).mediaSrc(0)
```

to get the URL specified in the first asp file.

Comment: If the first file is included in the second file, then the second file has access to the values of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to load the page using the filesystem as a text stream, then parse the page text yourself. Classic ASP pages are not objects, so `fileSrc(0).mediaSrc(0)` will not work.

Comment: Thanks! I looked into Session variables, but in my situation the user won't necessarily visit the first pages to open the session. So this seems the best option. Now to bone up on regular expressions!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to share information between pages would be to use session variables.

Remember to clear the those variables to avoid memory issues.

For more information on session variables:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp